# Map a list of a list javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

I try to display items from the following list :

```
const dataItems = [
{'key': '1','label': 'Informations Basiques', 'icon' : 'person', 'fields': [{'field':'Nom', 'value':'Piedigrossi'}, {'field':'Prénom', 'value':'Guillaume'}, {'field': 'Mail', 'value': 'guillaume.piedigrossi@gadz.org'}]},
{'key': '2','label': 'Téléphone', 'icon' : 'phone', 'fields': [], 'values': []},
{'key': '3','label': 'Adresse', 'icon': 'place', 'fields': [], 'values': []},
{'key': '4','label': 'Etat civil', 'icon': 'location-city', 'fields': [], 'values': []},
{'key': '5','label': 'Professionel', 'icon': 'school', 'fields': [], 'values': []},
{'key': '6','label': 'Informations familiales', 'icon': 'group', 'fields': [], 'values': []},];
```

Here is my code in react native :

```
render(){

    return(

        <View style={{}}>
           {dataItems.map(({item}) => (
              <Text>{item.key}</Text>
           ))}
        </View>)}
```

And I have the following error : "undefined is not an object (evaluating item.key)

I don't understand why the item.key doesn't reference to something.
Especially I would like to display the "field" and the "value" of the item "fields".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `{}` you put around `item`. That's the ES6 shorthand notation for destructuring an object, and using the `item` property of the object as the parameter. You only need to put `{}` around Javascript expressions inside HTML elements, not inside normal JS code like function parameters.

It should be:

```
dataItems.map(item => (
    <Text>{item.key}</Text>
))
```

You actually *can* use destructuring here to get the `key`:

```
dataItems.map(({key}) => (
    <Text>{key}</Text>
))
```

Comment: @azium thanks, I think I even answered a question once where that was the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

While Mapping you need to follow the destructuring the ES6 concepts.

1. Key reference error: you need to provide a unique key to each text which refers to

   ```
   <Text key={item.key}> { item.label}</Text>
   ```
2. You need to pass fatarrow functionality while destructruring.

   ```
   { 
        dataItems.map(item =>
           return <Text key={item.key}>{item.label}</Text>
   })
   ```

While using Fatarrow function and destructuring, you don't need to add function braces **()** you can set it as such above mention.

Also not included **{}** in between return if single line reference is going to return

Answer (score 0):

can you try this instead?

```
{dataItems.map(item => {
   return <Text>{item.key}</Text>
})}
```

I don't know react native, but I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are destructuring the elements by the `{item}` notation.

You do not need to do that. Changing your code to:

```
{dataItems.map(item => (
    <Text>{item.key}</Text>
))}
```

should do the trick.